# issues with multiple forms on php page

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to make a simple login system, with password recovery option,, so i made a password reset link.
hwoever, it is not working, meaning that form2's button just leads back to form1 (leads back to username and email form && i have three different forms), so i separated it into three different if statements, for each button clicked, but the same issue keeps on happening.

please tell me what is happening and ho to fix it

thank you.

(code is below)

```js
//not actually js, but is php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password'])){
    header("Location: changepass.php");
}
if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")) {
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpass = "";
  $db = "test";
  $con = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db) or die("Connection failed: %s\n". $con -> error);

  $GLOBALS['email'] = $_POST['email'];
  $GLOBALS['username'] = $_POST['username'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM login WHERE email='" . htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['email']) . "' and username = '". htmlspecialchars($GLOBALS['username'])."'");
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  //Part 1
  if($_POST['submit1']) {
    if($count==0) {
    echo  "<script>
     document.getElementById('error').innerHTML += 'Invalid Username or Email.';
    </script>";
    } else {
    echo  "<script>
     document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'none';
    </script>";
    echo  "<script>
     document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'inline-block';
    </script>";
    echo  "<script>
     document.getElementById('verify').innerHTML += 'A verification email has been sent to you. Copy the verification code and paste it above.';
    </script>";
    $GLOBALS['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(3));
    echo $GLOBALS['token'];
    $to = $GLOBALS['email'];
    $subject = "Password Reset";
    $msg = "Hello. Your token is <strong>" . $GLOBALS['token'] . "</strong>. <br>Good day.";
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    $headers = "From: email@example.com";
    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
  }
}
//Part 2
if($_POST['submit2']) {
    if($_POST['code'] != $GLOBALS['token']) {
      echo  "<script>
       document.getElementById('error2').innerHTML += 'Invalid verification code.';
      </script>";
    } else {
      echo  "<script>
       document.getElementById('next').style.display = 'none';
      </script>";
      echo  "<script>
       document.getElementById('final').style.display = 'inline-block';
      </script>";
    }
  }
      //Part 3
      if($_POST['submit3']) {
            $np = $_POST['np'];
            $cnp = $_POST['cnp'];
            if($np != $cnp) {
              echo  "<script>
               document.getElementById('error3').innerHTML += 'Passwords do not match.';
              </script>";
            } else {
              $sql = "UPDATE login SET password='$cnp' WHERE email=" . $GLOBALS['email'];
              $rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
              if($rs) {
                echo "Changed password successfully! Click <a href='login.php'>here</a> to sign in.";
              } else {
                echo "An unknown error occurred. Please try again.";
              }
            }
          }
}
 ?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Reset Password</title>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset>
<legend>Reset Password</legend>
<form name="frmContact" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div id="main">
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" style="display:inline-block" name="email" id="email" required autofocus />
<br>
<br>
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" style="display:inline-block" name="username" id="username" required />
<br>
<p id="error" style="color:red"></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="submit1" value="Reset Password" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="login.php">Create an Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
</p>
</div>
</form>

<form name="frmContact2" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<div id="next" style="display:none;">
  <p id="verify" style="color:green"></p>
<label for="code">Verification Code</label>
<input type="text" style="display:inline-block" maxlength="6" name="code" id="code" required autofocus />&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style="color:red;display:inline-block" id="validatecode"></p>
<br>
<p id="error2" style="color:red"></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="submit2" value="Reset Password" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="login.php">Create an Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="login.php">Sign in</a>
</p>
</div>
</form>

<form name="frmContact3" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<div id="final" style="display:none;">
<label for="np">New Password</label>
<input type="text" style="display:inline-block" name="np" id="np" required autofocus />&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style="color:red;display:inline-block" id="validatenp"></p>
<br>
<label for="cnp">Confirm New Password</label>
<input type="text" style="display:inline-block" name="cnp" id="cnp" required autofocus />&nbsp;&nbsp;<p style="color:red;display:inline-block" id="validatecnp"></p>
<br>
<p id="error3" style="color:red"></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit3" id="submit3" value="Reset Password" />
</p>
</div>
</form>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of debugging remove all extra stuff from that file and focus on 3 if statements

Also try using

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
```

Always try to close in onto the problem at hand and remove extra stuff that is in there. It helps make simpler but better decisions.